# Wordpress header and footer

Tags: wordpress, header, footer, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working in custom wordpress theme but wondering how wordpress decides to which link or script should be added in footer or which script should be added in header because we add all the links in the functions.php without mentioning that where it needs to be added.

Would be great if anyone could explain!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question.  Here is a good place to start - [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

We usually use the `wp_enqueue_script` function for including any script or style's file. In this function you can see there are few parameters are allowed.

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

You can see the last parameter us `$in_footer`, you can set it true if you need  to load the script/style in the footer. By default it is false and load in the `<head>` area.
For more details you can read the official information [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).